# escaping hashtags in regular expressions in sql

Tags: php, sql, hash

I'm using an sql query to search my table of posts for hashtags then a word. E.g. `#cats` I'm using `regexp` because it enables me to use a regular expression to find something in the string matching `#cats` but with a pattern.

The problem is I think the `#` is breaking the query. Here's my query,

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE something regexp '[[:<:]]#cats[[:>:]]'");
```

I've tried this to escape the `#`

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE something regexp '[[:<:]]\\#\cats[[:>:]]'");
```

Could anybody help me escape this hash, it is annoying me to so much :(

Comment: Can you post an example of the sort of data in your database you think should match yor regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is no word boundary between a space and `#`.

Try this instead:

```
WHERE something REGEXP '#cats[[:>:]]'
```